# Webscrapping IEEExplorer in Python

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I would like to experiment webscrapping to automated my technological watch on IEEExplorer.

My goal is to get the year, title and abstract of all the articles with the key word "deep learning" and "radar" (for instance) published after 2017.

The problem is only on IEEExplorer because it worked on Google Scholar.

Could somebody help me?

Thank you
Pierrick

I tried :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Définir l'URL de recherche avec les mots clés "Deep Learning" et "Radar"
url = "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?action=search&newsearch=true&matchBoolean=true&queryText=(%22All%20Metadata%22:Deep%20learning)%20AND%20(%22All%20Metadata%22:radar)&ranges=2017_2023_Year"

# Envoyer une requête GET à l'URL et récupérer le contenu HTML de la page
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

# Analyser le HTML avec BeautifulSoup pour extraire les informations nécessaires
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
articles = soup.select(".List-results-items")

# Parcourir tous les articles de recherche et extraire l'année de publication, le titre et l'abstract
for article in articles:
    year = article.select_one(".publication-year").text.strip()
    title = article.select_one(".title").text.strip()
    abstract = article.select_one(".description").text.strip()

    # Afficher les résultats
    print(f"Année de publication: {year}")
    print(f"Titre: {title}")
    print(f"Abstract: {abstract}")
    print("\n")
```

But "articles" is empty and I get :

```
soup = <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference #30.2e747e68.1677864420.73bb08c5
</p></body></html>
</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the appropriate headers first.

```
url = "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?action=search&newsearch=true&matchBoolean=true&queryText=(%22All%20Metadata%22:Deep%20learning)%20AND%20(%22All%20Metadata%22:radar)&ranges=2017_2023_Year"

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Host': 'ieeexplore.ieee.org',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

# Envoyer une requête GET à l'URL et récupérer le contenu HTML de la page
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Upon visiting your URL, I see that the webpage is making a `XHR` request to load the data.
You should scrape their API endpoint directly, since the HTML will give you nothing.

Here's their JSON Endpoint:

```
json_data = {
    'action': 'search',
    'newsearch': True,
    'matchBoolean': True,
    'queryText': '("All Metadata":Deep learning) AND ("All Metadata":radar)',
    'ranges': [
        '2017_2023_Year',
    ],
    'highlight': True,
    'returnFacets': [
        'ALL',
    ],
    'returnType': 'SEARCH',
    'matchPubs': True,
}

response = requests.post('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/search', headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you're looking for is obtained from different URL via Ajax call. To get them you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0",
    "Referer": "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org",
}

api_url = "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/search"

payload = {
    "action": "search",
    "highlight": True,
    "matchBoolean": True,
    "matchPubs": True,
    "newsearch": True,
    "queryText": '("All Metadata":Deep learning) AND ("All Metadata":radar)',
    "ranges": ["2017_2023_Year"],
    "returnFacets": ["ALL"],
    "returnType": "SEARCH",
}


response = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))

for r in response['records']:
    print(r['publicationDate'])
    print(r['articleTitle'])
    print(r['abstract'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
25-27 March 2021
Comparative Study Between Deep Learning Techniques and Random Forest Approach for HRRP Based Radar Target Classification
Target recognition and classification are challenging problems in [::radars::]. [::Radars::] can generate variety of measurements depending on the capabilities of specific [::radars::]. Out of the various types of the [::radars::], High Resolution [::Radar::] Range Profile (HRRP) measurements are one of the important [::radar::] target signatures that can be used for target classification. In this...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-16 Dec. 2021
Deep Learning Based Radar Target Classification Using Micro-Doppler Features
Demand for [::radar::] automatic target recognition is ever increasing owing to the extensive employment of [::radar::] sensors in urban scenarios and a drastic increase in the number of [::radar::] targets, especially drones and UAVs. Micro-Doppler signatures, resulting from the micro-motion dynamics of targets, have emerged as a key distinctive feature for [::radar::] automatic target recognitio...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22-26 April 2019
Deep Radar Detector
While camera and LiDAR processing have been revolutionized since the introduction of [::deep::] [::learning::], [::radar::] processing still relies on classical tools. In this paper, we introduce a [::deep::] [::learning::] approach for [::radar::] processing, working directly with the [::radar::] complex data. To overcome the lack of [::radar::] labeled data, we rely in training only on the [::ra...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-19 Dec. 2021
Deep Learning for Interference Mitigation in Time-Frequency Maps of FMCW Radars
With the substantial increase of the FMCW [::radars::] used for autonomous driving and other applications in the area of surveillance, mutual interference has become a major concern. Recently, [::Deep::] [::Learning::] (DL) models have been used in FMCW [::radar::] interference mitigation with great success, but no research has been conducted in processing the time-frequency (t-f) maps of acquired...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-16 July 2021
Deep learning for surface precipitation estimation using multidimensional polarimetric radar measurements
Traditionally, polarimetric [::radar::]-based rainfall estimates are derived through empirical parametric relations obtained from nonlinear regression between rain rates and simulated [::radar::] data. The performance of such empirical relations is highly dependent on the variations of raindrop size distribution. In real applications, such empirical algorithms often need to be adjusted for differe...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```